# datagridview_cellmousedown & datagridview_mouseenter

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-n-drop

Добрый день! Как получить индекс строки при наведение курсора на строку без datagridview_mouseenter? Или как включать datagridview_mouseenter только если включено datagridview_cellmousedown?

Цель:
Использую dragDrop, необходимо во время перетаскивания, в момент когда левая кнопка мыши зажата и держит в себе выделенные записи из другого датагрида, получить индекс строки первого датагрида над котором сейчас находится курсор.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел как решать, возможно костыль.

```
            Point dscreen = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            Point dclient = gridShift.PointToClient(dscreen);
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = gridShift.HitTest(dclient.X, dclient.Y);
```

Comment: Почему же, это не костыль. `PointToClient` правильно применён.