# DragDrop HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

В `DragDrop` пытаюсь получить индекс строки куда бросаю. Всё хорошо, только он почему-то получает индекс равный -4, если у строки индекс равный 1, то ниже приведенный код ей дает индекс 4. С чем это может быть связано?

```
private void gridShift_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int currentMouseOverRow = gridShift.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: Я на основе ваших прежних вопросов осмелился угадать язык и винформс. Всегда указывайте тэги. `gridShift` - это `DataGridView`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, но я решил проблему, решение вот тут
[ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535960/datagridview-cellmousedown-datagridview-mouseenter/535987#535987). Вопросы связаны были.